# Inverses of nxn matrices using bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening! I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed with the following question.

Let a = $v_1,...,v_n$ and b = $w_1, ...,w_n$ be a basis in $R^n$

Let A and B be nxn matrices, A = [ $v_1,...,v_n$] and B = [$w_1, ...,w_n$].

Let C be an identity matrix with respect to a and b, C = $[I]_a^b$.

Need to show why A = BC, and C = $B^{-1}$A.

Since A and B are nxn matrices, I guess I can use determinant and invertibility to show that A is similar B . But can I really use it here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use determinants.

If $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors, then the matrix $A = [v_1,\dots,v_n]$ is the matrix which maps $e_i \mapsto v_i$. Similarly, $B$ maps $e_i \mapsto w_i$.

So by taking inverses, you see that $A^{-1}$ is the matrix which maps $v_i \mapsto e_i$, and similarly $B^{-1}$ maps $w_i \mapsto e_i$.

Then the composition $BA^{-1}$ maps $v_i \mapsto e_i \mapsto w_i$. So $BA^{-1}$ is the identity matrix with respect to the bases $a$ and $b$.

(So I feel like maybe you have it backwards, since you said $C = B^{-1}A$, unless you consider matrices to act on the right, instead of the left...)

Comment: Hm, interesting. My initial thought was to use similarity and determinants. Like If A and B are nxn matrices and similar,  then there exists an invertible P, such that A = $PBP^{-1}$ and then plugging it to initial A = BC, where C is the Identity and it's basically $PP^{-1}$.

Comment: What makes you think that $A$ and $B$ are similar, though? I don't think anything in the question indicates that they are. They are just two random invertible matrices.

Comment: I thought since they nxn, they are diagonaziable. But I made a mistake to think that they are similar.